# How to make mht files being seen as thumbnails in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

How to make mht files being see as thumbnails in nautilus?
Nautilus can see html files thumbnails, that give a hope there is a way to do its with mht.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this as yet, because mht files are compressed archives, and Nautilus would need a new thumbnailer plugin to support them.

You can open a bug report requesting this feature on [GNOME's Gitlab for Nautilus](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues?label_name%5B%5D=4.+Newcomers).